# How to focus a custom view when writing a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need help with my VS Code extension. I've written a custom view which works just fine, however I'd like to activate / focus / bring into view that view by using a keyboard shortcut or a context menu command. I am unable to find how to use the VS code API to achieve that.

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('extensionId.showView', () =>
{   
    // how to do that?
}));
```

I know this can be done, because one can display the file explorer by using this code snppet:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.view.search');
```

But how would you do that for a custom tree view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [new `focus` option that was added to `TreeView.reveal()` in 1.25](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_custom-views) for that. The method requires you to pass a tree item to be revealed, so it's more of a workaround for not being able to focus the view itself directly, but you could simply pass the first / root node.

```
treeView.reveal(item, {focus: true});
```

Note that focus in this case means *keyboard focus*. If you just want to bring it into view, calling `reveal()` without the focus option is good enough.

To obtain a `TreeView` instance, you need to call `vscode.window.createTreeView()` with your view ID and provider.

Comment: Awesome. We're almost there :) The only thing left is why does the call to

view.reveal(item, { focus: true });

causes a compile error, since TreeView<T> supports only the following method (focus property is missing in the second parameter):

reveal(element: T, options?: { select?: boolean }): Thenable<void>;

Do I need to upgrade my dependencies in package.json? I am using VS Code 1.25.0, in devDependencies I'm referencing "vscode": "^1.1.18" and my engine is set to "vscode": "^1.22.0". Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to use the `focus` option, you should update both of those (devDependencies and engine) to 1.25.0.

Comment: I've tried to do that, but without success. NPM returns an error saying: No matching version found for vscode@1.25.0. I've also checked on NPM websate and it says the latest version is 1.1.18. I've checked the VS Code 1.25.0 documentation describing new features, but for some reason I'm unable to use the new API. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot: the versioning of the NPM package doesn't match the versioning of VSCode itself. `1.1.18` is indeed the latest version. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: The error message: Argument of type '{ focus: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ select?: bolean; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'focus' does not exist in type '{ select?: bolean; }'.

And here's the methods signature that I'm trying to invoke (so the error message makes sense, since there's no focus property present): 
`reveal(element: T, options?: { select?: boolean }): Thenable<void>;`

Comment: Hm, it works fine for me.. you _did_ update to `"engines": {"vscode": "^1.25.0"}` and ran `npm install` afterwards, right? And you also have `"postinstall": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install"` in your `package.json`? That seems to trigger this during `npm install`: https://i.imgur.com/gD3uAJx.png

Comment: Ok, that took some jumping through hoops, but I managed to make it work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I think, it is also possible to use

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("exampleView.focus")
```

using the exampleView declared in *package.json*:

```
...
"views": {
            "exampleView": [
                {
                    "id": "exampleView",
                    "name": "Example View"
                }
            ]
        },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Empiire said, focus command in the form of : **vscode.commands.executeCommand**

and adding the '.focus' at the end of the id of the view that was declared in the package.json works!

You can also provide an object as parameter such as { preserveFocus: true } to show without disturbing the current focus.

eamodio does it like that in gitlens : https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/blob/417587d0dfcda89e9e2d723f8b662d7cf9008c8f/src/webviews/webviewViewBase.ts#L85