# Can vscode's tree view api activate the specified element in some way?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Just like the built-in file selector, when the file is opened, the sidebar automatically expands to the file

> VSCode API: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to focus a custom view when writing a VS Code extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237836/how-to-focus-a-custom-view-when-writing-a-vs-code-extension)